# Type initialization exception when using Rebus load balancer

Tags: c#, load-balancing, producer-consumer, rebus

I'm using `Rebus` with `MSMQ`. I have tried Rebus with a scenario where my producer is sending messages to consumer in different machine and it works fine.

Now I need to use multiple consumers and need to distribute the load between them. I ran the sample in http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/3621 in the producer machine. But I got the following exception from the load balancer from the first line.

I have a queue named distributor in my local machine and my worker queues exists and their names are correct

> "Could not load type 'Rebus.Logging.RebusLoggerFactory' from assembly
>   'Rebus, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.":"Rebus.Logging.RebusLoggerFactory"

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the load balancer is old and does not work with "Rebus 2" (which is Rebus versions 0.90.0 and above).

You can easily implement a load balancer yourself with Rebus though, as you can simply create an endpoint that uses Rebus' built-in transport message forwarding capability.

[This answer](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/535#issuecomment-246839192) demonstrates how to configure transport message forwarding by calling `AddTransportMessageForwarder` when configuring Rebus.

The advantage of doing it this way, is that it saves the message from going through lots of steps (e.g. deserialization, handler lookup, etc.), and therefore it is very fast.

Of course this leaves it completely up to you to implement your load balancing algorithm. It could be so simple that it would simply be started with an array of queue names to pick from, and then it would simply [round-robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) between them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. By doing a bit of research, I thought of using a rabbitmq ha cluster with the ha-proxy load balancer. Now I'm trying to connect to my load balancer from rebus but I don't know how to setup the connectionstring for rebus. When I connect to the nodes individually by their connection string it works well (eg:amqp://test:test@10.182.40.68:5672 ). Only when I modify the connectionstring to use the load balancer it does not work. My load balancer connectionstring is amqp://10.182.40.220:5670. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?